# Matching and counting combination in python/panda

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge file with around 1 million rows and 4 columns. The columns that I want to analysis are A and C. The names in column A are repeating more than one time, but each time matched with a unique name in column C. I am looking for 4 specific names in column C and I want their correspond name in column A.
I want to have all the names from column A with any combination of the 4 names from column C and also want to count them how many of each combination there are.
I know it is confusing I show in an example:

Original file:
I am looking for TI,NB,CC and LR in column C and their correspond name in column A.

```
    A                B           C         D
   GB1                          TI
   GB2                          NB
   GB3                          VH
   GB1                          NB
   GB2                          CC
   GB6                          TI
   GB1                          LR
   GB1                          CC
   GB8                          JK
   GB9                          TI
```

Results That I want:

```
 Name:         Name from column C:
  GB1          TI, NB,LR,CC
  GB2          NB,CC
  GB6          TI
  GB9          TI
```

Also I want to know how many of each combination there are:(around 20 possible combination)

```
Combination:          Number:
TI,NB,LR,CC             1 
NB,CC                   1
TI                      2
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out all the combinations, you can group data frame by `A` and join all items from column `C` after sorting the items (for the count of combination purpose); To find out how many combinations there are, you can do a *value_counts()*:

```
items = ["TI", "NB", "CC", "LR"]
# use isin method to filter the data frame so that the results only contain interested items
# ignore the sort_values here if the order of the combination matters here
df1 = df[df.C.isin(items)].groupby("A").C.apply(lambda g: ','.join(g.sort_values()))
df1

#A
#GB1    CC,LR,NB,TI
#GB2          CC,NB
#GB6             TI
#GB9             TI
#Name: C, dtype: object

df1.value_counts()

#TI             2
#CC,LR,NB,TI    1
#CC,NB          1
#Name: C, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly what I want. Sorry I am not very familiar with programming, can you please help, how I can save the results in  a excel file?

Comment: I also have another question: in column C for "LR", its name some times is "LRR". What can i do, that program doesn't assume them as separate name and count them as one name?

Comment: To save the results in excel, I guess `df.to_excel(...)`? And to treat `LR` and `LRR` the same, one way is to replace `LRR` with `LR` using `df.C.replace("LRR", "LR")`.